# Unity inputfield in android hide when click on inputfield

Tags: unity-game-engine, right-to-left

I have a problem with `inputfield` in unity.

In Android, when I click on inputfield keyboard opens for ones and close again, I should hold my finger on inputfield for typing, and also have this problem in windows editor. Is there anyone who known the answer?

[image]

Comment: what your input field inspector looks like

Comment: inspector image: https://ibb.co/jGzQxw

Comment: Custom text-component with input-field could be causing this problem. Create an issue here: [UPersion](https://github.com/ElectroGryphon/EGGA/issues).

Comment: The same problem happened with Unity's own inputfield in this scane! and i test with new scane and Worked well!

Comment: Any solution for this, mine is the same case for 4 digit OTP - 4 separate inputs & at every input keypad gets hidden